# How to flush/clean cache programmatically in Magento 2.4 for category/product page

Tags: full-page-cache, magento2.4.2, category-view, product-view-page, flush

Like I mentioned in my question I am having a problem with cleaning/flushing cache on category/product pages.

I get some code, probably for some older version of Magento but didn't work.

Here it is:

```
    $cacheTag = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $catId;
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($catId, $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());

    $this->cacheManager->clean(\Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG, [$cacheTag]);
    $this->eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $category]);
```

The same example I found here:

https://magecomp.com/blog/clear-cache-for-specific-cms-page-programmatically-in-magento-2/

I check Manager class and method clean have only one parameter(argument) and this is an array of types. So I tried with one argument and I get one error: `Notice: Undefined index: instance in /app/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/TypeList.php online 75`

So is there any other way how to clean cache on the category or product page?

Tnx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Version;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool;

class YOURBLOCKCLASS 
{

    protected $cacheTypeList;
    protected $cacheFrontendPool;
 
    public function __construct(TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, 
    Pool $cacheFrontendPool)
    {
    
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    }
 
    public function MyCustomcacheFunction()
    {
       $_types = [
            'config',
            'layout',
            'block_html',
            'collections',
            'reflection',
            'db_ddl',
            'eav',
            'config_integration',
            'config_integration_api',
            'full_page',
            'translate',
            'config_webservice'
            ];
 
        foreach ($_types as $type) 
        {
            $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }

        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) 
        {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
    }
}
```

Now call your Block function by creating the object of block class where you want to do the caching.

Comment: Thank you for response. This code will clean/flush all categories or just categories that I want? I need clean/flush just few of them (i am saving category_id in database table and then within foreach I am trying clean/flush cache with cache tag cat_c_id ).

Comment: then you can pass the category id on function call and check if you want to perform for that one or not.